# Stack Overflow vs Super User?

Tags: discussion, tags, superuser

What is the difference between Stack Overflow and Super User?

Like how come when I just asked a question on what I thought was Stack Overflow it posted it on Super User?

Does it just randomly get dropped on a Stack Exchange sub-page? Is there some reasoning here? Maybe it's based on the tags that are added?

Comment: [Super User on-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) versus [Stack Overflow on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Also [Super User questions to avoid](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask) versus [Stack Overflow questions to avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: If you want a brief overview of what a site in the community is about, then visit their [tour].

Answer (score -14):

User *Some programmer dude* made [a good comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413224/stack-overflow-vs-super-user#comment880648_413224) that I thought was a sufficient answer, so here are some links distinguishing the two sub-sites mentioned in the question:

[Super User on-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

[Stack Overflow on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: And yet since this Q&A you have posted on Stack Overflow a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70071989/2227743) that is not related to programming. Looks like you need to read these pages again. :)